# How to make DataGrid column ReadOnly in runtime using code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagridview, webforms

How to make ASP.NET DataGrid column Read-only in run-time using code behind?

I know this can be done in ASPX:

```
<ASP:BoundColumn HeaderText="MHN"  ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MHNNum" DataField="MHNNum" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"
```

But I want to do this using code behind Vb or C#. Strangely I don't see Readonly property being exposed to DataGridColumn.

The following does not work:

```
Dim col as DataGridColumn=DGDrid.Columns(0)

Col.readonly=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
 ((BoundColumn)DGDrid.Columns[0]).ReadOnly = true;
```

For the Vb:

```
 CType(grdWaiver.Columns(0), BoundColumn).ReadOnly = True
```

Comment: For the Vb. Developer:
CType(grdWaiver.Columns(0), BoundColumn).ReadOnly = True

Comment: Nice. You can edit my answer and add that in. Also Could you please mark it as the correct answer.